# Regex matching numbers greater than a decimal value

Tags: regex, numbers, decimal

The regex I want to write must match all the numerical values greater than `0.01` and with maximum of two digits after the decimal point.

For matching all the numbers with maximum of two digits of the decimal point the regex which works is `"^\\d+(?:\\.\\d{1,2})?$"`.

I've researched on the internet about regex greater than some values but only found examples of regex greater than integers which does not work the same.

Any suggestions?

Comment: XY problem? Why do you need this? Just parse it and compare. For [codegolf.se]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm not sure if this fully address your rquirements I wasn't able to comment but I think you can filter zero matchees by a lookahead: `(?!0+\.0+$)^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$`

Comment: I think this is very close to what I want, the difference is that it checks for values greater than 0.1 instead of 0.01. Also it says 0 is ok which isn't corect

Comment: i think i made a mistake please check it now.

Comment: @user202729 What do you mean? I think it is pretty clear. It should match all numerical values greater than 0.01 and with no more than 2 digits after decimal points

Answer (score 0):

To match a numerical value greater than `0.01` with a maximum of two digits after the decimal point you might use a negative lookahead `(?!` at the start of the string to assert that one or more zeroes with an optional dot `.` zeroes part does not occur until the end of the string or that the string starts with `0.01`.

[`^(?!0+(?:\.0+)?$|0+\.01$)\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$`](https://regex101.com/r/fsRJDk/1)

This will for example also not match `0`, `0.0`, `0.00`, `00000000000`

**Details**

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `(?!` Negative lookahead which asserts that what is on the right is not

  - `0+(?:\.0+)?$` Match one or more zeroes with an optional part that matches a dot and one or more zeroes and assert the end of the line
  - `|` Or
  - `0+\.01$` Match one or more zeroes followed by .01 and assert the end of the line
- `)` Close negative lookahead
- `\d+` Match one or more digits
- `(?:\.\d{1,2})?` An optional part that would match a dot followed by one or two digits
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line